# How can I prove this estimation of the Lipschitz constant of the mollifier: $[u_\epsilon]_\leq [u]$?

Tags: real-analysis, convolution, lipschitz-functions

I consider $u\in C^{0,1}(\Omega)$ a Lipschitz function with $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ open.

Let be $[u]_{C^{0,1}(\Omega)}=\sup _{x,y\in\Omega, x\neq y}\dfrac{|u(x)-u(y)|}{|x-y|}$ the Lipschitz constant of $u$.

I consider $u_\epsilon=u*\rho_\epsilon$, defined on $\Omega_\epsilon=\{x\in \Omega |dist(x,\Omega)>\epsilon\}$,

where $\rho_\epsilon(x)=\epsilon^{-n}\rho(\dfrac{x}{\epsilon})$ and 
$$\rho(x) = \begin{cases} e^{1/(1-|x|^2)}/I_n& \text{ if } |x| < 1\\
                 0& \text{ if } |x|\geq 1
                 \end{cases},$$
( $I_n$ is a coefficient of normalization).

How can I prove that $[u_\epsilon]_{C^{0,1}(\Omega_\epsilon)}\leq[u]_{C^{0,1}(\Omega)}$?

I don't know how to do it. Can someone help or give me a reference?
Thank you!

Comment: 1- The usual definition of mollifier is slightly different than yours [(wiki link)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier#Notes_on_Friedrichs.27_definition). Did you mean $\rho_\epsilon (x) = \frac{1}{\epsilon^n}\rho(\frac{x}{\epsilon})$? 2- Do you have condition on $\epsilon$ other than being positive? 3- Is your set $\Omega$ a general set or maybe a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @iamvegan 1)yes, thank you,  I made a mistake in writing $\rho_\epsilon$ 2) $\epsilon>0$ is the only condition on $\epsilon$ 3)I consider $\Omega\in\mathbb{R}^n$ open.

Comment: Hint: Start by writing the difference $u_\epsilon(x) - u_\epsilon(y)$, and expand out the convolutions. (There are a few different ways to write the convolutions--you may have to try a few ways before you find the most convenient one.) At some point, you know that you have to use the Lipschitz estimate $|u(x) - u(y)| \leq L|x-y|$.

Comment: @user37208 Thank you very much for the hint!

Comment: @user37208 I found your hint very helpful. Using that idea it's just couple of lines to justify the estimation.